# jQuery Blur Animate and Click conflict

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, blur

I've got a search bar that slides down and when hit a button and slides up when you blur the field. There's an issue however with clicking the button while the field is in focus. It'll trigger the slideup animation which will follow up with the slidedown animation when the first animation completes.

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('.bar').animate({
        marginTop: "0"
    }, function(){
        $('.bar input').focus();
    })
})

$('.bar input').blur(function(){
    $('.bar').animate({
        marginTop: "-2em"
    })
})
```

Here's an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/mattcoady/6ncER/1/

Opening the menu works fine and clicking in the white space works fine. Clicking button while the menu is open causes the animation to trigger after the first. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a class to designate whether the menu is up or down:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    var $bar = $('.bar');
    var isUp = $bar.hasClass('up');
    var isAnimating = $bar.is(':animated');

    // Either this menu is already down or it's animating, 
    // so don't register the click
    if(!isUp || isAnimating) {
        return;    
    }

    // Slide down the menu 
    $bar.removeClass('up').animate({
        marginTop: "0"
    }, function(){
        $('.bar input').focus();
    })
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ncER/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can just cancel logic if element is animated: {if i get what you are looking for?!}

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mattcoady/6ncER/1/)

```
if($('.bar').is(':animated'))return;
```